# Python. Проблемы с list

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list, for

Хочу написать программу для физики. Весь день делал расчеты по физике, но ошибка расчетов более 10 %. В итоге психанул, и решил программу написать, да еще не в си, как я привык, а в питоне, чтобы расчеты были более точными. Компилятор в питоне выдает ошибку. Не могу понять что именно не правильно , хотя в си все работает:

```
        Cкорость: 
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "fff.py", line 14, in <module>
        speed_glitserin[i] = l / time_glitserin[i]
        IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Вот код на питоне

```
    print("Cкорость: ")
    l = 0.5
    time_glitserin = [5.15, 5.01, 4.73, 7.6, 6.96]
    speed_glitserin = [] * 5
    for i in (0,5): 
    speed_glitserin[i] = l / time_glitserin[i]
    print(speed_glitserin[i])
```

Вот тот же код на си, но он работает:

```
    #define SIZE 5
    float l =0.5;
    float skorost_gl[SIZE] = {};
    float t_gl[SIZE] = {5.15, 5.01, 4.73, 7.6, 6.96};
    printf("Скорость :\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
           skorost_gl[i] = l / t_gl[i];
           printf("v%d = %.3f\n", i + 1, skorost_gl[i]);
        }
```

Comment: А что именно неправильно? Нам надо догадаться?

Comment: Извиняюсь , вопрос немного некорректно задал. В питоне выдает Cкорость: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fff.py", line 13, in <module>
    speed_gl[i] == l / time_gl[i]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Это тот же код, но имя переменных поменял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно выбрали параметр для for
Решением проблемы будет заменить строчку с for на

`for i in range(0,5):`
[image: Просто описание]

Но и тут все не так просто. Когда вы сделали так

`speed_glitserin = [] * 5`

ничего не произошло. Для вашего удобства, чтобы массив был любого размера в вашей программе в будущем, можно использовать `speed_glitserin.append(значение)` это добавит в конец массива значение, которое вы укажете. В итоге правильным кодом будет:

```
l = 0.5
time_glitserin = [5.15, 5.01, 4.73, 7.6, 6.96]
speed_glitserin = []
for i in range(0,5): 
    speed_glitserin.append(l / time_glitserin[i])
    print(speed_glitserin[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
for i in (0,5):
```

на

```
for i in range(0,5):
```

В первом случае у вас берутся два числа 1 и 5. А элемента номер 5 в списке нет.

Во втором случае берутся числа от 0 до 4.